# WCF Service Hosting technique

Tags: wcf, iis, service, windows-services, hosting

We have a WCF service called service1 hosted in IIS.

We are creating another WCF service, say, service2, which will always be running in the background and will monitor if a file, say, X, is having enough data that has to be consumed by Service1.

If the file X is not having enough data then service2 will call another component which will load the data to the file.

So please suggest a hosting technique for service2 which fulfils all the above requirements and should be independent, i.e if the service2 is down, it should not impact service1 or vice versa. Both these services are a part of the same app-domain.

We have one scenario where we hosted the same as a window service. Now we are looking to try something else.

Please provide your valuable suggestions.

Comment: I changed "Abdomen" to "app-domain" in my edit. I hope this was correct.

Comment: Why was a windows service not the correct solution for you?

Comment: Hi Tom..Thanks for the correction :)
Windows Service is a correct solution for this which fulfills our requirement but we are building a new system and were thinking to try something else basically to experiment something new :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the right kind of screwdriver to hammer a nail. 8-)

WCF services run on demand, based on network activity (a request comes in, the service runs and handles the request). However after a defined period with no activity the service shuts down and the resources are released, and the server waits for the next request, however the existence of a file containing the data you want does not create this type of request.

What you need is a Windows Service (the things that you see in the Services Control Panel). These run continuously and are appropriate for tasks that don't produce network requests, like monitoring to see if you have the data you need.

> We have one scenario where we hosted the same as a window service. Now we are looking to try something else.

There really isn't anything else suitable for unattended operation. Windows Services are designed exactly for this type of task, while WCF Services aren't.

Comment: Thanks terry for your valuable feedback. :) 
But apart from window service is there something else you can think to implement this ?

Comment: You could write a "check my file" service in WCF and execute it with something like wget.exe. (windows clone of a *nix utility), that you called form a scheduled task. It's an ugly hack but would work. Unfortunately there are a limited number of ways to check for a condition then perform an action, without having a user logged in.

Comment: If you have a SQL server, you can do something similar in SSIS.

Comment: If you have a SQL server, you can create an SSIS package that watches for your file data and then does whatever you need, but I wouldn't trust an SSIS package to run forever, watching for your data, because they tend to eat up resources.

Comment: Hi Terry, just one more thing I wanna ask you. As both the services will be in same app domain, one will be hosted in IIS and other as a Window Service. So how I can ensure that  if the service2 is down, it should not impact service1 or vice versa ?

Comment: I have mine updating and checking a processing queue in a database so if one or the other is down the processing queue just waits

Comment: OK, I'm not typing on my phone now so I can add more detail. 8-) You could use Message Queuing like MSMQ, however I chose to use the database because it allows better visibility into the state of the system. It's easy to query and see what's waiting and why, etc. If you don't need this, MSMQ is a lighter weight alternative. In any case, you do need to make sure that if one or the other is down, everything doesn't just die.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from your hosting requirement you should also consider using a [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) if you haven't done so already. You would obviously have to add  your own logic to meet your requirements.

Basic example:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
   FileSystemWatcher Watcher = new FileSystemWatcher("some file path");
   Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
   Watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(Watcher_Changed);
} 

// This event is raised when a file is changed
private void Watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
   // your code here
}
```

More complete example:

http://www.rhyous.com/2012/11/27/c-creating-a-service-to-monitor-a-directory/